# Android Accessibility Disabled Button Hint

Tags: android, accessibility, talkback

I have a button that is disabled when certain requirements are not met, like most applications.

When using TalkBack I get the output "[Button Text], Button, Disabled"

What I want to achieve is "[Button Text], Button, Disabled, [hint as to why]"

Comment: What is your current code?  What did you try to add the hint?

Comment: Not sure that current code matters. Question is just for any use of Button.
I have not been able to find anything related to adding a hint that is spoken after the disabled state is. So have not been able to try much at this point. 

Setting content description isn't going to help since that's spoken before the values added by the system

Comment: Ah, I see. I don't think there's any way to do that, unfortunately.  The only bits that are read after the Disabled state in TalkBack are things relating to collections and actions (e.g., click).

Comment: Okay, might have to push back on that requirement but seems like something that should exist. I won't pretend I understand a whole lot about how visually impaired folks interact with mobile devices, but it seems like having context as to why a button is disabled would be very useful. I guess I could create a custom class and just manage the content description myself but I was hoping to avoid that route.

Comment: Personally, I don't like disabled buttons, I like errors to be on the screen. If you made a live region (https://mobilea11y.com/blog/android-live-regions/) you could display an error for all users and the announcement would be read aloud.